# Sending POST request to an Endpoint results in "binding element must be a struct"

Tags: python, go, struct, request, put

I have an endpoint that I wrote in Go using the Echo library. I am trying to POST data via a python script, but am getting a "binding element must be a struct" error.

Code from Endpoint where I bind the request body to a variable (Go lang):

```
// get body from request
requestBody := make(map[string]interface{})
    if err := c.Bind(&requestBody); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Python script:

```
data = {
    "AED": {
        "USD": 0.2719
        },
    "ARS": {
        "USD": 0.0142
    }
}

 headers = {
        "Authorization": # my_jwt_token,
        "API-Key": # my api_key
    }

 requests.put(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
 
 if not response.ok:
     raise Exception("Failed to update")

 return result.status_code
```

Error message:

```
{"logType":"application","msg":"Status: 400, Error: code=400, message=binding element must be a struct, Title: Client Error, Message: binding element must be a struct, Detail: ","action":"Error Handler","level":"error","timestamp":"2020-07-13T13:39:19-07:00"}
```

Why is this happening? I can use Postman to send the exact same Payload and it works fine, but sending a PUT request with python requests library does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. "data" field in post request should be changed to "json".